# Exception in @JmsListener reverts jmsTemplate.convertAndSend

Tags: spring-boot, jms

I have a similar setup like this:

```java
@Component
public class ServiceA() {
  @Autowired
  private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void foo() {
     jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("a", "MESSAGE");
     // here I store to the DB that message was sent to destionation "a"
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class ServiceB() {
  @Autowired
  private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void foo() {
     jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("b", "MESSAGE");
     // here I store to the DB that message was sent to destionation "b"
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class ServiceC() {
  @Autowired
  private SomeHttpClient client;

  @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void foo() {
     client.send("MESSAGE");
     // here I store to the DB that message was sent to the other system via HTTP
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class MyJmsListener() {
  @Autowired
  private ServiceA a;
  @Autowired
  private ServiceB b;
  @Autowired
  private ServiceC c;

  @JmsListener(destination = "bar")
  public void listenToBar(String message) {
     a.foo();
     b.foo();
     c.foo(); //throws exception
  }
}
```

So as you can see, I have three service classes and each has its own JPA transaction. The thought behind this is, if the call in ServiceC (to another system fails), in the retry of the JMS listener, call for `ServiceA.foo` and `ServiceB.foo` will be skipped. I ommited the checks for simplicity.

Anyway, now the call `c.foo()` throws an Exception because the other system that it wants to communicate with is not available. Now the issue: No messages are written to the queues that are supposed to be written. It seems that something rolls back my `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend`

I can reproduce this using a Spring Boot Test, when `c.foo()` does not throw an Exception, everything works fine, but as soon as an exception is thrown, no messages end up in the queues.

What am I missing?